# Show compass blueprint grid

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Is it possible to show compass blueprint grid to see its layout.

Here is the sample that I want to achieve:

http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/grid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, include the showgrid mixin (`+showgrid` in the original SASS syntax):

```
#my-container
  +showgrid
```

You do, however, need to generate the image for your particular grid flavor:

```
$ compass grid-img W+GxH [path/to/grid.png]
# Where:
# 
# W = Width of 1 column in pixels.
# G = Width of 1 gutter in pixels.
# H = Height of the typographic baseline in pixels.
```

Comment: with the latest compass version it isn't necessary to create the grid image cause compass shows it now with css3.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the class showgrid to your container

if you inspect element on that page and remove the showgrid class you'll see it disappear